# Calculating percentage changes without dividing by zero

Tags: php, math, divide-by-zero

I have the following the PHP that I am using to calculate percentage decreases or increases:

```
function CalculatePercentageIncrease( $nLastMonthPeriod, $nCurrentPeriod ) {
    if ( !is_numeric( $nLastMonthPeriod ) || !is_numeric( $nCurrentPeriod ) )
        return 0;

    if ( $nLastMonthPeriod == 0 )
        return 0;

    $nLastMonthPeriod = intval( $nLastMonthPeriod );
    $nCurrentPeriod = intval( $nCurrentPeriod );

    $nDifference = ( ( ( $nCurrentPeriod - $nLastMonthPeriod ) / $nLastMonthPeriod ) * 100 );

    return round( $nDifference );
}
```

The problem that I am wondering about is if `$nLastMonthPeriod` is 0 and `$nCurrentPeriod` is 10 then should it be returning 100 and not 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **if $nLastMonthPeriod is 0** and $nCurrentPeriod is 10 then should it be
>   **returning** 100 and not **0**?

Thats what you coded ...

```
  if ( $nLastMonthPeriod == 0 )
        return 0;
```

did you mean?

```
  if ( $nLastMonthPeriod == 0 )
       if ($nCurrentPeriod>0)
          return 100; //whatever you want
       else
          return 0;
```

Answer (score 8):

An increase from 0 to 10 can not be described as a percentage increase. You need to treat that case separately.

The answer is not 0 % or 100 %.

Either

1. tell the users of the function that it's only valid when the old value is != 0
2. use exceptions
3. return NULL (suggested by Jack Maney)

Comment: But the problem I am having is that $nLastMonthPeriod is generated automatically and isnt user controlled so should it just not be returning anything cause theres any data from last month and it cant divide by zero?

Comment: Well, every time the program (in my words: 'the user') calls this function you need to make sure what you want the program to actually do in case of division by zero. Then you use NULL or exceptions to figure out that it occurred. If for example you display a graph showing the returned value you may want to make it grayed out. If print some text or symbol indicating what happened. No magic number will do. If you assign for example 0 for this case people will think that last value was also 10. If you put 100%, people will think it was 5, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't divide by zero (for many reasons, both technical and mundane), it would probably be best to return `NULL` when `$nLastMonthPeriod==0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put in a check:

```
$nDifference = $nLastMonthPeriod == 0 ? 100 : ( ( ( $nCurrentPeriod - $nLastMonthPeriod ) / $nLastMonthPeriod ) * 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function percent($small, $large){
    if($large !=0){
    $percentCalc = ((100*$small)/$large);
    $percent = number_format($percentCalc, 1);
        return $percent;
    } else {
    return '0';
}
}
```